# Use selected MAX value of a table to join another table in single query

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Can I use selected **MAX** value of a table to join another table in single query ??I am trying this in magento .Here is my code :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('merc/checkin_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->join(array("table1"=>"table1"),"main_table.id = table1.checkin_id",array('MAX(table1.checkout_id) as max_checkout')) 
->joinleft(array("table2"=>"table2"),"table1.max_checkout = table2.id",array('table2.check_time as checkout_time'));
```

here I am selecting **MAX(table1.checkout_id) as max_checkout from "table1" and using "max_checkout" for joining table2**...this is not working for me ..even I have tried with main_table.max_checkout instead of table1.max_checkout for joining second table.If this is possible..Can anyone help me out??